# How to take backup of database in SQL server on network location through a job?

Tags: sql-server, backup

I need to take the backup of database in SQL server on network location through creating a job in SQL server 2005.

can anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Maintenance Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189953%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)
It will create a job manageble through Sql Server Agent, altenatively you can use SSIS (however the Maintenance Plans use SSIS).

One note, in the configuration of the backup activity you can browse only local path, however you can input the network path manually

Answer (score 0):

Agree, backup location can be used as a UNC location.
Can be managed by a maintenance plan or backup command in the SQL Agent job